# Textbox multiline imprimindo apenas ultimo item

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu estou usando `TextBoxt Multiline` para fazer a "emissão" do relatório no próprio sistema.
Ta imprimindo, porém, aparece a seguinte mensagem: "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" e em seguida, o dado.

```
public Formulário()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamReader ler = new StreamReader(@"escrevesaida.txt"))
    {
        string leitor;

        while ((leitor = ler.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText($"{leitor}{Environment.NewLine}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se o objetivo é separar linha a linha, a melhor forma será:

```
string leitor;

while ((leitor = ler.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    textBox1.AppendText($"{leitor}{Environment.NewLine}");
}
```

Colocando o seguinte código antes do `while`:

```
leitor = ler.ReadLine();
textBox1.Text = leitor;
```

Estava a "apanhar" a 1ª linha e só depois as restantes. Pode colocar tudo dentro do ciclo.

---

Em relação ao texto `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 123`, realmente, como o @ThiagoMagalhães referiu, parece ter origem em `textBox1.Text += textBox1;` ou algo do género. A não ser que isso já venha do ficheiro...

Comment: O Código todo da função ficou assim... E ainda da aquela mensagem "System..."

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (StreamReader ler = new StreamReader(@"escrevesaida.txt"))
            {

                string leitor;

                while ((leitor = ler.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText($"{leitor}{Environment.NewLine}");
                }

            }
        }

Comment: Poste o código da classe toda na sua questão, pode ser que encontremos algo.

Comment: Como é que foi criado o ficheiro "**escrevesaida.txt**"? Numa outra aplicação? Manualmente?

Comment: Foi criado no sistema. Eu uso o bloco de notas para inserir dados de saída numa outra tela. Porém abro e fecho o StreamWrite na tela em questão.

Comment: Pode colocar o conteúdo do ficheiro na sua questão? Assim conseguiríamos validar a solução do nosso lado.

Comment: São dados inseridos através do programa, de forma manual. Coloquei dados aleatórios. São dados aleatórios, números inteiros.

Comment: Como está a utilizar o `StreamWriter`? Por acaso não está a fazer o seguinte: `sw.WriteLine(textBox1);` ao invés de `sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);`?

Comment: string valor = txtvalor.ToString();

Comment: Estou usando assim.

Comment: Aí é que está o erro :). Tem que fazer `string valor = txtValor.Text;`, caso contrário está a atribuir uma representação em texto do tipo do controlo.

Comment: Ainda assim da o mesmo erro. ;/

Comment: Acho que deu certo agora.

Comment: Ainda bem! Marque a resposta como útil e/ou correta, se o ajudou :)

Comment: Essa é minha quarta pergunta aqui, eu não sei como faz isso. MUITO OBRIGADO PELA AJUDA.. Foi de grande valia.

Comment: Se puder me orientar, agradeço, e já faço aqui .

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que no `Text` do `textBox`, para cada linha que ele lê você está atribuindo o valor, substituindo o valor que tinha anteriormente.

```
textBox1.Text = leitor;
```

O correto seria concatenar, ou seja, juntar os resultados de cada linha. Da seguinte forma:

```
textBox1.Text += leitor;
```

Comment: Correto, Resolvemos um problema. Só que ta aparecendo o resultado precedido de 
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 123

Comment: Está aparecendo: `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 123` no campo?

Comment: Sim Sim, o dado correto é 123, porém aparece essas coisas antes ai.

Comment: em algum lugar do seu código, você deve estar fazendo: `textBox1.Text += textBox1;`

Comment: Não, porque é uma tela nova, e, a função é privada.

Comment: Dê uma olhada se você realmente não está fazendo isso por acidente...

Comment: Eu até olhei, mas não tem nada. Inclusive, aí está 90% do código. Anterior à isso tem as partes padrões do Visual ... As funções padrões..